# character data type is listed under integer type

Tags: c++

I was studying C++ and came across [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) link for data types. In first table, character type is listed even under signed and unsigned integer category:

character types char    Exactly one byte in size. At least 8 bits.

Integer types (signed)  signed char Same size as char. At least 8 bits.

Integer types (unsigned)    unsigned char   (same size as their signed counterparts)

What does this mean? Does this mean that we could use char type in place of 8 bit integer as we typically do for 8 bit data in C?
For example, below code is legal even in C.

```
unsigned char index;
int ar1[]={4,5,6,7,8};
for(index=0;index<5;index++)
cout<<ar1[index]<<"\n";
```

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) does not list char under integer category.

Secondly, is the above usage of unsigned char for index is safe in C++? Are we going to save memory in this usage or will it not save anything? Or is there any performance issue if we use char type?

Comment: cppreference is not a standardization entity, it is certainly not a reference despite what the name suggests.

Comment: [\[basic.fundamental\]/2](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#2)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yet it's a best one we have so far.

Comment: You can use any c++ standard draft, highly available on the net. @liliscent link is perfect.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès How about the site http://www.cplusplus.com? Is this trusted? My first part of the question is related to the information given at this site.

Comment: @Rajesh Prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) to that one.

Comment: @Rajesh - On "saving memory": In a normal PC you have billions of bytes of memory. Saving memory - meaning not using the memory even though it is there anyway - should perhaps not be the primary focus when writing a program.

Comment: @Rajesh also note on "saving memory": in such a small example, your `index` value will plausibly never exist in memory, rather only in a register, at which point it will be whatever the native word size is (i.e. int)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out the existence of data types such as `(u)int{n}_t` where n is size in bits, which since c++11 do signed and unsigned integers of specified sizes and are unlikely to be mistaken for characters.
[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

(cannot comment yet)

Answer (score 0):

Using an unsigned char is perfectly fine for the example you gave.  What will happen is when you call `ar1[index]` is the `unsigned char` will converted into a `size_t` before the call; and since the unsigned char is known to be smaller or the same size as size_t there will be no warning issued by the compiler.

> Do you save any memory?

Well; yes outside the call to `[]`.  Since the type is converted on the call, you will end up having to use more than that much memory later since you can't pass that item by reference.  On the other hand if your `index` variable is to last the life of the program; and you plan to have a lot of them; then the space saving can make it worth while.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtlety of language employed by the standard. It describes "signed integer types", "unsigned integer types", and "integral types" (a.k.a "integer types"), which are `bool`, `char`, `char16_­t`, `char32_­t`, 
`wchar_­t`, and the signed and unsigned integers.

The headings in cppreference's description of the fundamental types are non-normative, and exist to highlight that character types represent character values, in addition to being integers.